# How do I find the first occurrence of a vowel and move it behind the original word (pig latin)?

Tags: python, findfirst

I need to find the first vowel of a string in python, and I'm a beginner. I'm instructed to move the characters before the first vowel to the end of the word and add '-ay'. For example "big" becomes "ig-bay" and "string" becomes "ing-stray" (piglatin, basically).

This is what I have so far:

```
def convert(s):

    ssplit = s.split()
    beginning = ""
    for char in ssplit:
        if char in ('a','e','i','o','u'):
            end = ssplit[char:]
            strend = str(end)
        else:
            beginning = beginning + char
    return strend + "-" + beginning + "ay"
```

I need to find a way to stop the "if" statement from looking for further vowels after finding the first vowel - at least I think it's the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: You could use a flag to see if you found the first vowel and then make your if statement only run if the flag is 'down'

Comment: Note: You can do `if char in 'aeiou':`

Answer (score 2):

Break things down one step at a time.

Your first task is to find the first vowel. Let's do that:

```
def first_vowel(s):
    for index, char in enumerate(s):
        if char in 'aeiou':
            return index
    raise Error('No vowel found')
```

Then you need to use that first vowel to split your word:

```
def convert(s):
    index = first_vowel(s)
    return s[index:] + "-" + s[:index] + 'ay'
```

Then test it:

```
print(convert('pig'))
print(convert('string'))
```

Full code, runnable, is here: https://repl.it/Dijj

The exception handling, for words that have no vowels, is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `break` where you want the for loop to end: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: This answer would be improved by adding a code sample within the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

Python has the `break` and `continue`statements for loop control.  You can set a boolean that you trigger such that:

```
if flag:
    break
#do code
#set flag
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `break` statement as soon as you found a vowel. 
You also do not need to use any `split()` functions.
One big mistake you did was using `char` to get the `SubString`. You need to use the index of that char to get the `SubString` instead.

Take a look at this:

```
def convert(s):
    beginning = ""
    index = 0;
    for char in s:
       if char in ('a','e','i','o','u'):
           end = str(s[index:])
           break
       else:
           beginning = beginning + char
       index = index + 1
    return str(end) + "-" + beginning + "ay"
```

Answer (score 0):

Side note. You can use a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> cases=['big','string']
>>> for case in cases:
...    print case+'=>', re.sub(r'^([^aeiou]*)(\w*)', '\\2-\\1ay', case)
... 
big=> ig-bay
string=> ing-stray
```